# Android Background Service causes a lot of crashes

Tags: java, android, service, crash

I have an background service for an instant massanger which causes lot of crashes (around 10.000 per day).

What I've done: im starting the Service with `onStartCommant` and return `START_STICKY`.

`onDestroy()` and `onTaskRemoved()` calls an broadcast which restarts the Service so it will newer die and this works mostly.

Now I recognized that android device manager gives the advice to set it to standby because there are too many crashes (in background the user will not notice it).

Here is my Service:

```
public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass, Context c) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static MassageDataSource getMassageDataSource() {
    return massageDataSource;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    if (context == null) {
        context = this;
    }

    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);
    if (massageDataSource == null) {
        massageDataSource = new MassageDataSource(context);
        massageDataSource.open();
    }

    startTimer();
    return START_STICKY;
    //return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(context, RestartService.class);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(context, RestartService.class);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}

public void startTimer() {
    //set a new Timer
    timer = new Timer();

    //initialize the TimerTask's job
    initializeTimerTask();

    //schedule the timer, to wake up every 1 second
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000); //
}

/**
 * it sets the timer to print the counter every x seconds
 */
public void initializeTimerTask() {
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            Log.i("in timer", "in timer ++++  " + (counter++));
        }
    };
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

and this is my Broadcast:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(RestartService.class.getSimpleName(), "Service Stopped!");

    if (!BackgroundService.isMyServiceRunning(BackgroundService.class, context)) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent service = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getForegroundService(context, BackgroundService.SERVICE_ID, service, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        } else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, BackgroundService.SERVICE_ID, service, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        }
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), intervall, pendingIntent);

        Log.i(RestartService.class.getSimpleName(), "Service restarted.");
    } else {
        Log.i(RestartService.class.getSimpleName(), "Service is already running");
    }
}
```

The service runs 8 seconds, then is got stopped and got restarted by the Broadcast which works. But every time it got destroyed is is crashing and produced this output on logcat:

```
 Thread[3,tid=17948,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x75b3a16400,peer=0x13b80020,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

 Wrote stack traces to '[tombstoned]'

 D/ConnectivityManager_URSP: Ursp sIsUrsp=false, sIsCheckUrsp=false, uid=10291

 D/Proxy: urspP is null: 10291

 I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package com.test.module1
 I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package com.test.module2

 D/SensorManager: registerListener :: 10, TMD4906 lux Sensor, 66667, 0,

 I/RestartService: Service Stopped!
 I/RestartService: Service restarted.
```

I read that `START_STICKY` is causing that so I tried other commands but only with `START_STICKY` my service is not going to die.

Also for some reasons the Service is not starting on boot.

Comment: I'm not sure but the timerTask could be the reason. Why don't you cancel the task in onDestroy and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: I tried but no changes

Answer (score 0):

The Android framework will keep service alive alive(or re-create it for you) if you return [START_REDELIVER_INTENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT), [START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) and related flags.

The description in doc for [START_REDELIVER_INTENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT):

> Constant to return from `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)`: if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int))`, then it will be scheduled for a restart and the last delivered Intent re-delivered to it again via `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)`. **This Intent will remain scheduled for redelivery until the service calls `stopSelf(int)` with the start ID provided to `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)`**.

So i would recommend to implement with Android`s framework behavior with returning [START_REDELIVER_INTENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) to make service run again after being killed by any reason without calling `Service.stopSelf()` or `Context.stopService()`.

But if you required to do it with broadcast mechanism, maybe just return [START_NOT_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY) to prevent system do it for you. And system will not recreate the service which will cause the `onStartCommand()` be invoked multiple times and cause the crash.

Refer to [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#constants_2) for more details about [`onStartCommand()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)).

Comment: I tried to delete startBroadcast() in onDestroy and in onTaskRemoved() and changed return START_STICKY to return START_REDILIVER_INTENT. But now after the App is closed the Service is dead forever and is not restarting. Android is not trying to restart my service

Comment: I tried also the second advice and used START_NOT_STICKY. Now it seems there are now no crashes but there is now the advice from the device manager to set the app to stadby because of "app do not react".

Comment: There is something strange going on:                                                     I/RestartService: Service Stopped!
 I/RestartService: Service is already running So for some reasons onDestroy or onTaskRemoved is calles but the Service still runs

Comment: @Jones Service not restarting: How do you start the service first time? If you use the `Context.bindService()` to create service it will be killed after all connection unbind. Use `Context.startService()` before `Context.bindService()` if you do.

Comment: I do not use bindService() i'm starting with startService() after I checked if the service is already running

Comment: Have a quick confirm, the `onStartCommand()` will not invoked if restart by system, would you mind to move the original code(timer/sqlite) to `Service.onCreate()`?

Comment: I moved everything from onStartCommand() to Service.onCreate() except context=this and return START_NOT_STICKY. Backgroundservice is still not running forever.

Comment: Sorry, I`m out of source to figure out this, maybe this sample can help you find out what is going on [RestartServiceSample](https://gist.github.com/LarryHsiao/fbc294c202df9c9f30c8a94d052d9d31) which I can see it is restarted normally by System after app process killed.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

As recomendet above I'am returning now START_NOT_STICKY. But that couldn't solve the problem. So I decided to use startInForeground for api>=26 (Android Oreo).
Now the Service is alive forever and there are no problems.

The only thing I dont like is of course, that there is a notification all the time.
I wanted a background service like for example Whatsapp uses. Their background service runns all the time and if it got destroyed or something else there appears a notification "you could have new messages" and then the service is alive again and the notifiacation is disappering.

So what I have done now:

-Broadcast is still the same

-Background service:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("BackgroundService", "onCreate was called");
    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);
    messageDataSource = new MessageDataSource(this);
    messageDataSource.open();
    startForegroundService();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    Log.i("BackgroundService", "onStartCommand was called");
    context = this;
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}


public void startForegroundService() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        ChannelID = createNotificationChannel("app_service_1", "Benachrichtigungen", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
    } else {
        ChannelID = "app_service_1";
    }

    startForeground(101, buildForegroundNotification("Sie könnten neue Nachrichten haben")); //should use resource string
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(context, RestartService.class);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(context, RestartService.class);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}

private Notification buildForegroundNotification(String message) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ChannelID);
    b.setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("MyApp")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(com.app.R.drawable.schloss_deutsch4);//dauerhafte Benachrichtigung in der Leiste
            //.setSmallIcon(1); //aufgrund eines Fehlers läuft der Dienst dauerhaft aber ohne Benachrichtigung

    return (b.build());
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private String createNotificationChannel(String channelId, String channelName, int importance) {
    android.app.NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
            channelName, importance);
    chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    NotificationManager service = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    service.createNotificationChannel(chan);
    return channelId;
}
```

So I tried to use startForegroundService() in onDestroy() and in onTaskRemoved() and deleted startBroadcast() also tried with startBroadcast() and stop the Notification with stopForeground(true) in onCreate() or in onStartCommand().

The idea: if the service got destroyed because its running in background without notification I will fade in a notification and if the service is stable again I will remove this notification again.

Is there any possibility to reach this?